# Easy way to find multiple words at line and column using CMD, Powershell or GNU utilities

Tags: powershell, batch-file, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to determine the contents of the third column for the 4th, 5th, 6th and 7th lines of a `Powershell` Measure Command/Elapsed Time results and write each of the four words to four separate text files and later used as variables.   This will be done in a Windows batch file, but I have access to CMD, `Powershell` and GNU utilities.

I was using this command, but Null values were inserted and sometime it wouldn't capture values.

```
sed -n 4p C:\Temp\ElapsedTime.txt > C:\Temp\ElapsedTime_Hours_Null.txt | cat C:\Temp\ElapsedTime_Hours_Null.txt | tr -d '\000' > C:\temp\ElapsedTime_Hours.txt
```

I don't know if this would work any better.

```
cat C:\Temp\ElapsedTime.txt | tr -d '\000' > C:\temp\ElapsedTimeConcatenated.txt
sed -n 4p C:\Temp\ElapsedTimeConcatenated.txt | awk "{print $3}" > c:\temp\Hours.txt
```

I don't know the easiest way to go about this given my limited experience with CMD, `Powershell` and GNU utilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- PowerShell creates UTF-16LE-encoded files by default (using `>` / `>>` and `Out-File without the`-Encoding` parameters).
- GNU utilities cannot directly process such files, so you need to translate them to UTF-8.

  - Your `tr -d '\0'` approach will only work if your file contains *only* ASCII characters.
  - Otherwise, either create the file as UTF-8 to begin with, or use a conversion utility such as `iconv`.
- However, if PowerShell created the input file, it may be easiest to **stick with a PowerShell solution**, where you needn't worry about the file's encoding:

It sounds like your input file contains the text-formatted representation of a `[timespan]` object, such as the following:

```
Days              : 1
Hours             : 12
Minutes           : 30
Seconds           : 45
Milliseconds      : 400
Ticks             : 1314454000000
TotalDays         : 1.5213587962963
TotalHours        : 36.5126111111111
TotalMinutes      : 2190.75666666667
TotalSeconds      : 131445.4
TotalMilliseconds : 131445400
```

If that's the case, it is more robust to parse by *property name* rather than *line index*:

```
set-location -ea Stop c:\temp

# Read the time-unit values into individual variables.
$hours, $minutes, $secs, $ms = (Get-Content ElapsedTime.txt) -match
  '^(Hours|Minutes|Seconds|Milliseconds) ' -replace '.*: '

# Output to separate ASCII text files.
# (Remember, `>` / `>>` and `Out-File` produce UTF-16LE files by default).
$hours    | Out-File -Encoding ASCII hours.txt
$minutes  | Out-File -Encoding ASCII minutes.txt
$secs     | Out-File -Encoding ASCII seconds.txt
$ms       | Out-File -Encoding ASCII ms.txt
```

---

As for a solution based on **using *GNU* utilities in a *batch file***:

```
@echo off
setlocal

cd /d "c:\temp"
iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 ElapsedTime.txt | tail -c+4 |^
awk "BEGIN { split(\"hours.txt:minutes.txt:seconds.txt:ms.txt\", names, \":\") } NR>=4 && NR<=7 { print $3 > names[++n] }"
```

Note: The command uses `iconv` to convert the UTF-16LE file created by PowerShell to UTF-8, and then uses `tail -c+4` to skip the 3-byte (pseudo-)BOM (`0xef`, `0xbb`, `0xbf`, customary on Windows only) created by `iconv`.

If you don't have `iconv` and the input file contains *ASCII characters only*, you can convert the UTF-16LE file to a pure ASCII file by simply removing the `NUL` chars. from the input file and skipping the 2-byte BOM (`0xff`, `0xfe`, which typically prints as `ÿþ`):

```
tr -d "\0" < ElapsedTime.txt | tail -c+3 | ...
```

Comment: I saved your code as a Powershell script and was able to get it working in my Windows batch file with this command >>  powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File c:\temp\ExtractTimeValues.ps1  (Carriage Return)  At the moment, I don't have my computer setup to run unsigned Powershell scripts.     Thank you very much for your answer and Powershell expertise!     I hope others can answer it using other DOS or GNU utilities for those who don't know how to do it in Powershell.

Comment: @noni: I've added a GNU utilities / batch-file solution - the output filenames may not match the input file line indices (not sure what fields you're looking for exactly, and if there's whitespace in your input file, but you get the idea. I encourage you to make your question clearer to benefit future readers.

Comment: The text results appear correct, but when I use the following --
    set /p Hours=<C:\temp\hours.txt
    set /p Minutes=<C:\temp\minutes.txt
    set /p Seconds=<C:\temp\seconds.txt
    set /p Milliseconds=<C:\temp\ms.txt

The final output results as --
Elapsed Time:   ÿþ0 Hours, ÿþ8 Minutes, ÿþ5 Seconds, ÿþ5 Milliseconds

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Comment: @noni: It sounds like the files you're reading from are actually still UTF-16LE files, not UTF-8/ASCII. The `ÿþ` is how the UTF-16LE BOM (byte-order mark) prints. I've updated my answer to show how to remove this BOM - both when using `iconv` and when using your `tr -d "\0"`-ASCII-only shortcut.

Comment: You must make your files UTF-8/ASCII first. If your file is still UTF-16LE, then whatever `cmd.exe` sees will be cut off at the first `NUL`, which will be come after the first data byte. If you still have problems, please ask a _new, specific_ question, using an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I couldn't get the GNU utilities code to work. When I echo  %seconds:~2,3% -- or even %seconds:~2,20% (since two characters are included in the resulting text file) it only displays the first character.   Is there a way to have the Powershell code output to ASCII text?

Comment: See my previous comment to understand why only the 1st character is displayed. If you're creating the files from _PowerShell_ now, create them as _ASCII_ files with `Out-File -Encoding ASCII` - see my update.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell

```
(Get-Content input.txt)[3,4,5,6] | ForEach { ($_ -Split '[^a-z]')[2] } | Set-Content ParticularName.txt
```

PowerShell indexes are 0 based, and `Split()` assumes whitespace separated columns.

---

**Help Links** (if available):

- Get-Content is [`Get-Content`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) (in module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management)
- ForEach is an alias for [`ForEach-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300)
- Set-Content is [`Set-Content`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113392) (in module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management)

Comment: I tried the above command in Powershell, but I only got a blank text file -- or I didn't set it up correctly.

Comment: @noni I guess that the Split wasn't working, and I've edited my answer so it now does a regex split on runs of any non-alphabetic characters. That has more chance of doing *something*, but I can't guess if it will do the right thing. Consider editing your original question to include some examples of the file content you're working with.